# Как дождаться конца потока?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть код:

```
const readStream = fs.createReadStream("file");
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("file");

let test;
writeStream.on("finish", () => {
    test = "Yeah".
});

const pipeline = promsify(stream.pipeline);

await pipeline(readStream, writeStream);
console.log(test)
return test
```

Знаю такие варианты решения:

```
while(!test) {
  //Ну и  тут мы спим...
}
```

И такой вариант решения:

```
    const a = () => return new Promise(rsolve, reject) => {
       writeStream.on("finish", () => {
          test = "Yeah".
          resolve(test);
       }
    });

pipeline(readStream, writeStream);
await a()
```

Проблемы:

- Ну про `while` говорить не приходится...
- А вот с промисом... Так, как я сейчас написал - работает, но нужно обратить внимание, что перед `pipeline` отсутствует `await`.
  Если его добавить (`await pipeline(readStream, writeStream);`) - код замирает. Может его и не нужно ставить?

Как решить такое?

Comment: нода свежая?___

Comment: 14.17. Если ты про `stream/promises` - там еще их нет, они с 15, изначально было на них... P.S А там без `callbacka-а` можно подписаться? Я думал, что только на `pipeline` `promsify` не делать.

Comment: я тебе накидал несколько вариантов на чистом node.js, на все случаи жизни. а вообще, если тяжело, найди на npm какой-нибудь модуль работы/промисификации с потоками и не запаривайся

Comment: Спасибо, решил. P.S Ох я и намешал...

Comment: я, кстати, на выхах написал загрузчик на https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable :) посмотри на этот модуль

Comment: Выглядит очень хорошо. P.S Особенно любопытен benchmark, хотя, вероятно, это заслуга nodejs. В будущем, скорее всего, попробую. Хотя и с мультером неплохо ужился - кастомный движок дал полный контроль над загрузкой и возможности: подсчета хеш суммы, преобразования, шифрования, - в потоке, что очень радует.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для наглядности располагаю варианты от событийной работы с потоками до последнего `stream/promises`.

Вариант использующий только события потоков:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const filesrc = path.join(__dirname, './src.txt');
const filedest = path.join(__dirname, `./dest-${Date.now()}.txt`);

(async () => {
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filesrc);
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filedest);

  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      writeStream.on('finish', resolve);
      writeStream.on('error', reject);
      readStream.on('error', reject);
      readStream.pipe(writeStream);
    });

    console.log('done');
    console.log(await fs.promises.readdir(__dirname));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Вариант использующий `stream.pipeline`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');
const path = require('path');

const filesrc = path.join(__dirname, './src.txt');
const filedest = path.join(__dirname, `./dest-${Date.now()}.txt`);

(async () => {
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filesrc);
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filedest);

  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      stream.pipeline(readStream, writeStream,
        (err) => (err ? reject(err) : resolve()));
    });

    console.log('done');
    console.log(await fs.promises.readdir(__dirname));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Вариант использующий `stream.pipeline` и `promisify`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');
const path = require('path');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const filesrc = path.join(__dirname, './src.txt');
const filedest = path.join(__dirname, `./dest-${Date.now()}.txt`);

(async () => {
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filesrc);
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filedest);

  try {
    await promisify(stream.pipeline)(readStream, writeStream);

    console.log('done');
    console.log(await fs.promises.readdir(__dirname));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Вариант использующий `stream/promises`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream/promises');
const path = require('path');

const filesrc = path.join(__dirname, './src.txt');
const filedest = path.join(__dirname, `./dest-${Date.now()}.txt`);

(async () => {
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filesrc);
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filedest);

  try {
    await stream.pipeline(readStream, writeStream);

    console.log('done');
    console.log(await fs.promises.readdir(__dirname));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```