# Запись страницы в файл node.js

Tags: node.js

Есть страница google spreadsheets. Гугл эксель, проще говоря. Я подгружаю страницу через needle, а потом записываю `fs.writeFileSync('./table.html', spreadsheetsHtml, {encoding: 'utf8'});`. Но записывается почему-то с ошибками `Гру��па`. Беда в том, что needle выдаёт уже такой текст с ошибками. Но, насколько я знаю, он автоматически определяет кодировки. В чем проблема?

```js
const needle = require('needle')
const fs = require('fs');


needle.get('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQXRLX-aofeNtFqYUdnZEmOFmyW2mCjpOaoqLzpUPn1mKhLjDaLRXA3XjRXWpxWyXKMumMPOZ0cvnOu/pubhtml?gid=1239914093&single=true', function(error, response) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            fs.writeFileSync('./table.html', spreadsheetsHtml, {encoding: 'utf8'});
        }
});
```

Comment: Буду рад подсказке как получить и записать файл иначе. Чтобы без ошибок было

Comment: код, ссылка на файл

Comment: @nörbörnën обновил вопрос. Добавил код

Comment: Короче, просто сделал через request с указанием, что это utf8 кодировка `var request = require('request');
var iconv  = require('iconv-lite');

var opt = {
    url: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQXRLX-aofeNtFqYUdnZEmOFmyW2mCjpOaoqLzpUPn1mKhLjDaLRXA3XjRXWpxWyXKMumMPOZ0cvnOu/pubhtml?gid=1239914093&single=true',
    encoding: null
}

request(opt, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(iconv.decode(body, 'utf8'));
    console.log(res.statusCode);
});`

Comment: 1) библиотека request уже больше года сама говорит `request has been deprecated` 2) заморачиваться с перекодированием данных, которые и так приходят в utf-8 - пустая трата ресурсов

Answer (score 0):

В [документации](https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle) `needle` написано:

> needle returns a `readableStream` object

и это очень удобно, так как [readableStream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams) - фундаментальная штуковина в [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).

Возвращает поток? Значит будет писать этот поток прямо в файл, без всяких дополнительных ухищрений - node.js best practices!

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const needle = require('needle');

const filepath = path.join(__dirname, 'spreadsheet.html');
const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(filepath);
const spreadsheetsStream = needle.get(
  'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQXRLX-aofeNtFqYUdnZEmOFmyW2mCjpOaoqLzpUPn1mKhLjDaLRXA3XjRXWpxWyXKMumMPOZ0cvnOu/pubhtml?gid=1239914093&single=true'
);
spreadsheetsStream.on('error', console.error);
fileStream.on('error', console.error);

spreadsheetsStream.pipe(fileStream);
```

Обратите внимание, что работа с потоками сильно отличается от `fs.writeFileSync`, так что вам прийдётся подписаться на событие `finish` или `close`, чтобы дождаться окончания записи файла. Я показывал как это делать [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1292723/2659).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Завтра обязательно протестирую. Дам знать об успехе или провале теста)