# Как загрузить изображения с другого сайта на свой сервер Node.js (Express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Как загрузить файл в Node.js Express.js (имеется ввиду картинка - если известен только ее url в интернете)? Цель такая - есть массив с урлами - нужно скачать картинки из интернета по ним и записать полученные файлы на свой сервер.

Comment: А при чём тут экспресс?

Comment: В общем то ни при чем. Просто я подумал, что это имеет значение для решения этого вопроса.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback

Или готовые пакеты, axios, got, node-fetch и т.п.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Скачать файл по ссылке на диск с помощью axios](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1336012/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-axios)

Answer (score 0):

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const fs = require('fs');
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://somesite/something.jpg',
    responseType: 'stream'
})
    .then(function (response) {
        response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('something.jpg'));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: ответ в правильном направлении, но не очень хорош из-за того, что промис резолвится до того, как [закончится запись в файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1292723/2659)