# Как скачать файл через node js в проект

Tags: node.js

Стоит задача скачать файл по прямой ссылке (по ней сразу идет скачивание), после чего предстоит дальнейшая работа с ним. Было бы идеально сохранить этот файл в указанное место в проекте, что бы потом передать его в переменную. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать скачивание в проект и последующее удаление из него (скриптом).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Скачать файл на диск с помощью axios](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1336012/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-axios)