# Как скачать архив nodejs

Tags: node.js

Стоит задача скачать архив в указанную папку на NodeJs по ссылке которая сразу начинает скачивание, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать не используя посторонние пакеты (или используя node-fetch)

Comment: Я же Вам вроде ссылку давал на этот вопрос. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Comment: Дело в том что там обсуждается скачивание не zip файла. Я попробовал способ описанный там, однако архив скачивается поломанным.

Comment: Нет никакой разницы, какой файл скачивать. Если файл оказывается поломанным — приведите больше подробностей, как конкретно вы его скачиваете, как проверяете и откуда знаете, что файл не является поломанным изначально и его ломает именно nodejs

Comment: @ДмитрийКрутиков не плодите однотипные вопросы, добавляйте новую информацию в текущем вопросе, пока он не будет решен

Comment: ПО гайду написал данный код 
`const file = fs.createWriteStream("archive.zip");
const request = http.get("http://www.cbr.ru/s/newbik", function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);

    // after download completed close filestream
    file.on("finish", () => {
        file.close();
        console.log("Download Completed");
    });
});`
На выходе получаю в папке архив, который невозможно открыть так как выдает ошибку что он поврежден или имеет неверный формат

Comment: Или может подскажете вариант через fetch как сделать?

Comment: Попытался разархивировать содержимое через adm-zip и получил ошибку: Error: Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found

Comment: @ДмитрийКрутиков мой ответ не подошёл? я собираюсь его удалить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node.js v18.11.0`

```
import fs from 'node:fs';
import { pipeline } from 'node:stream/promises';

try {
  const res = await fetch('http://www.cbr.ru/s/newbik');
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(res.statusText || res.status);
  }

  const filename =
    res.headers.get('content-disposition')?.split(/\s*;\s*/).find((x) => x.startsWith('filename='))?.replace(/^filename=["']?|["']$/g, '')
    || 'archive.zip';

  await pipeline(
    res.body,
    fs.createWriteStream(filename)
  );
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}

export {};
```

```bash
~/tmp/q $ ls -1
20221112ED01OSBR.zip
20221112_ED807_full.xml
```

---

В вызов [pipeline](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/stream.html#streampipelinestreams-callback) можно добавить PipelineTransform и налету разархивировать загруженный архив.

---

Если нужен код на commonjs, можно воспользоваться моим [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1336020/2659) на вопрос "[Скачать файл на диск с помощью axios](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1336012/2659)".

Comment: отлично работает! наконец в Node.js добавили встроенную поддержку fetch (хоть и с ворнингом)

Comment: разработка `stream/promises` это нужная и важная вещь, а вот добавление fetch на реальную разработку никак не влияет